# How to delete some rows which has specific value at pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

sorry friend I have a dataframe in panda, I have a column that it has a value="**Total**" in some rows. I want to delete the rows which has "**Total**" value in it. before this stage I wrote several codes to make the dataframe like below:

[image]

and my code error is :

[image]

part of my codes are:

```
def Turk_Export_Excels(url,Tur_year,Tur_month):        
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
for i in range (9):                            # for deleting the 9 initial rows
    df=df.drop(i)
for j in range(4):                             # deleting the 4 columns which is useless
    df=df.drop(j, axis=1)                      # delete column
for j in range(5,12,1):
    df=df.drop(j, axis=1)                      # delete column
df=df.drop(13, axis=1)
for j in range(15,18,1):
    df=df.drop(j, axis=1)                      # delete column
for j in range(19,26,1):
    df=df.drop(j, axis=1)                      # delete column 
df=df.drop(26, axis=1)
for j in range(27,40,1):
    df=df.drop(j, axis=1) 

df=df.drop_duplicates(keep="first")

for i in range (0,100,1) :
    df.iloc[i,3]=str(df.iloc[i,3])
    df.iloc[i,3]=df.iloc[i,3].replace('.','')
    # if df.iat[i,1]=="Total":
        # df=df.drop(i)
df.drop(df.index[df['1'] == "Total"], inplace = True)
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: you simply want to delete the `Total` ? Is this your question?

Comment: @Tobias Molenaar  I don't know how to delete a row if it has a specific value? I always encounter an error in vscode? Could you help me how to write that part of code?

Comment: #Mehmaam The Row which Total exist in it.

Comment: `df = df[df['column_name'] != 'Total']`

Comment: @Tobias Molenaar should I put it in the if condition??

Comment: No that is not necessary

Comment: @Tobias Molenaar yes exactly like this link which you sent it. but I don't know why It doesn't work for me with this link guidance.

Comment: You need to share your data (not in excel), You only need the right dataframe name, column name and value name

Comment: @Tobias Molenaar you are right I think I put the wrong column name in it.

Answer (score 0):

Just do that:

```
df=df[df["1"] != "total"]
```

It deletes the rows containing "total" as value of the column "1"